# Размещение layout-a один под другим

Tags: android, xml

Мне нужно разместить два лейаута один под другим. Сверху должен стоять горизонтальный с двумя кнокнами, а внизу вертикальный с вложенным webView
Сейчас на верхний нализает нижний, как их разделить?

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/generateLinkButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
            android:text="Generate new article" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addToFavorites"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:drawable/btn_star"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </WebView>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно к первому LinearLayout добавить id
    `android:id="@+id/linear_layout_one"`

а у второго layout указать параметр:
`android:layout_below="@+id/linear_layout_one"`

который означает - что второй layout будет располагаться под первым

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout_one"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/generateLinkButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:text="Generate new article" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addToFavorites"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:drawable/btn_star"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_below="@+id/linear_layout_one"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </WebView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Прочитайте про ваш главный layout - RelativeLayout

http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/layout/relativelayout.php

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative

Comment: Спасибо. Все работает как надо .